# Multivariate chain rule confusion

Tags: multivariable-calculus, chain-rule

I recall (a version of) the multivariate chain rule: Let $z = f(x,y)$ be a differentiable function of $x$ and $y$, where $x = g(t)$ and $y = h(t)$ are themselves differentiable functions of $t$. Then
\begin{eqnarray} \frac{\partial z}{\partial t} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\frac{\partial x}{\partial t} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\frac{\partial y}{\partial t}. \quad \quad \quad (1) \end{eqnarray}
My confusion has arisen from asking, what if $y(t) = t$? Blindly following (1), we seem to have, 
\begin{eqnarray} \frac{\partial z}{\partial t} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\frac{\partial x}{\partial t} + \frac{\partial z}{\partial t} \quad \quad \quad (2) \end{eqnarray}
which is wrong, of course.. ((2) $\Leftrightarrow \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\frac{\partial x}{\partial t}=0$, but a counterexample: take $f(x,t)=x$ with $x(t)=t$, so $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\frac{\partial x}{\partial t}=1\neq0$).

So, to confirm, is (2) is incorrect? Why doesn't (1) work with just putting $y(t)=t$? And, most importantly, what should the correct version of (2) be?

Many thanks, and, sorry for an elementary question... I've just forgotten my multivariate calculus!

Comment: For $y(t)=t$ we have $\partial y/\partial t=1$. Substitute it to (1). I do not see how you get $\partial z/\partial t$ there. Your $z=z(t)$ is originally one variable function, no partial derivatives there.

Comment: The second term in the rhs of (1) is $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\frac{\partial y}{\partial t} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$ (and $f \equiv z$)

Comment: $f\equiv z$ is not true. It is $z(t)=f(x(t),y(t))$, but $f$ is not the same as $z$.

Comment: Take an example. $f(x,y)=x+y$ is a nice linear function with partials $1$ and $1$. Set $x(t)=\sin t$, $y(t)=t$ to get $z(t)=\sin t+t$. You see that the derivative $dz/dt$ has nothing to do with $\partial f/\partial y=1$.

Comment: It might be more clear to write (1) as $ z'(t) = D_1f (x (t), y (t)) x'(t) + D_2 f (x (t), y (t)) y'(t) $.  Here $ D_1 f $ is the partial derivative of $ f $ with respect to its first input.

Comment: I see now, my confusion came from the fact $f \not \equiv z$ ($f$ has variables $x,y$ and $z$ has variable $t$). Many thanks for the example in your explanation @A.G.